# Какое практическое применение имеет console.log()?

Tags: javascript

Для чего нужен этот метод - понятно. Интересно, используете ли вы `console.log()` на практике? Если да, в каких случаях?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Конечно используем.

1. Для отладки кода. Когда нет желания или необходимости просматривать каждый шаг в отладчике. Просто что-то вывел и смотришь, где что пошло не так.
2. Можно просто писать мелкие скрипты, которые делают что-то (да хоть какое-то вычисление), прямо-в консоли браузера - в таком случае console.log - это правомерный и единственный адекватный вывод.
3. В node.js console.log - это вывод в обычную консоль (stdout).

Answer (score 6):

Console.log() - отличный инстумент для отладки кода, не заметный для пользователя. Можно разбивать события на группы, а так же форматировать вывод.

```
var foo = {baz: "tubular", goo: "rad"}, bar = "baz";
console.log(
     "%2$d theory is %1$s %3$s concept. I can only describe it as %s and %s",
     "string",1,foo.goo,bar,foo.baz
);
```

Answer (score 4):

Кроме console.log() существуют методы console.warn() и console.error(). Отличаются чисто визуально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также в этом треде пригодится и информация о том, когда console.log() **использовать не стоит**.

В IE8 консоль создается только после открытия Инструментов Разработчика по F12, поэтому обращение вызов метода .log() у несуществующей консоли вызовет ошибку в коде. Кроме того, никто не гарантирует, что консоль будет и в других браузерах, которые могут использовать ваши пользователи (скажем, ужасные браузеры на "умных телевизорах" Smart TV).

Одно из решений - проверить, существует ли консоль, и заменить обращение к ней на пустую функцию:

```
if (!window.console) {
  var empty_func = function(){}; // Функция, Которая Ничего Не Делает
  console = {
    log: empty_func,
    warn: empty_func,
    error: empty_func
  }
}
```

Недостаток такого решения - консоль отключается насовсем, т.е. если она появится (пользователь нажмет F12), ничего выводиться не будет. В такой ситуации можно проверять наличие консоли перед каждым к ней обращением, написав свою функцию логгинга или переопределив console.

Кроме того, рекомендуется убирать вывод в консоль в боевой версии сайта, просто как меру предосторожности и уважение к чистоте пользовательской консоли :) Хотя есть и креативные обратные примеры: загляните в консоль сайта [One Plus](https://oneplus.net/).

Comment: А что будет с созданной консолью, если пользователь нажмёт F12 позже, когда код с `if`'ом уже отработал?

Comment: Можно сделать свою функцию логгинга, например myLog(аргументы), и в ней уже проверять - доступна ли консоль, стоит ли туда что-то выводить, или вывести алертом, или в абсолютно позиционированный див поверх экрана, или сохранить вывод в переменную, а потом вывалить весь целиком при появлении консоли и т.п. Все зависит от условий задачи и желания разработчика. Например, на мобильных устройствах консоль не видна и не всегда до нее достучишься. Или на embedded webkit. Это уже слегка за пределами данного вопроса, не находите? :)

Comment: Несомненно за пределами, но если вы уж приводите код, который другие будут использовать, почему бы не обсудить этот код?

Comment: Ок, добавил эту инфу в ответ.

Comment: @VladD, там с консолью гораздо больше шедевров чем кажется. Например, ошибку можно схлопотать на таком коде `window.console && console.log && console.log.call`. Обращаю внимание, что этот код лишь проверяет наличие свойств, но ничего не вызывает. Тем не менее, при открытой консоли будет *ошибка* (т. е. Exception), что свойства call нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy: То есть получается, что возможен race condition между проверкой наличия консоли и закрывающим её в этот момент юзером?

Comment: @VladD, неа. Там просто не только джаваскриптовые объекты существуют. А если объект не джаваскриптовый, то возможна ситуация, что ты вообще *не имеешь права* обращаться к свойству, которого у него нет и словишь exception, если попытаешься так сделать. Вот функции консоли оказались среди них.

Answer (score 0):

Для деобфускации неплохо подходит. Заменяете document.write и eval на console.log и смотрите что в консоль вывалит. Например,

```
eval('(false+"")[1]') // непонятно
console.log((false+"")[1]) // 'a'

console.log((Function("return{}")()+"")[2]) // 'b'
console.log(([]["filter"]+"")[3]) // 'c' 
//и т.п.
```

Comment: Эм.. Это каким образом?

Comment: Заменяете document.write и eval на console.log и смотрите что в консоль вывалит.

Answer (score -1):

`console.log()` использую для отлавливания ошибок.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?